# why ParallelDo seems to slow down the speed of each CPU by a factor of 2?

Tags: performance-tuning

```
AbsoluteTiming[Do[i, {i, 1, 100000000, 1}]]
```

gives: {10.1721, Null}.

While

```
AbsoluteTiming[ParallelTable[Do[i, {i, 1, 100000000, 1}], {j, 1, 12, 1}];]
```

gives: {21.5717, Null}.

My computer has 12 CPUs so the second expression should have taken roughly the same amount of time, right? However here it takes about 2 times long.

To confirm each Kernels takes twice long, I evaluated the following:

```
AbsoluteTiming[
ParallelDo[t1 = SessionTime[]; Do[i, {i, 1, 100000000, 1}]; 
t2 = SessionTime[]; Print[t2 - t1];, {j, 1, 12, 1}]]
```

The results are:

(kernel 2) 20.011529

(kernel 9) 20.448307

(kernel 6) 20.807406

(kernel 4) 20.841009

(kernel 11) 20.929293

(kernel 7) 20.874639

(kernel 10) 21.066614

(kernel 1) 21.084575

(kernel 8) 21.277364

(kernel 3) 21.310842

(kernel 5) 21.551988

(kernel 12) 21.786071

Out[26]= {21.8711, Null}

Why would ParallelDo seems to slow down the CPUs by a factor of 2?

Comment: What exact CPU model you do have?  Are you sure you have 12 physical cores instead of 6 with hyper-threading?

Comment: I ran the command "cat /proc/cpuinfo  | grep 'name'| uniq" and it gives "Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2620 v2 @ 2.10GHz".  Intel's webpage "https://ark.intel.com/products/75789/Intel-Xeon-Processor-E5-2620-v2-15M-Cache-2_10-GHz" says this CPU has 6 cores and 12 threads, and it uses the Hyper-Threading Technology. So is it because the first expression is actually using 2 threads, while in executing the second expression each kernel uses only 1 thread, so it is a factor of 2 slower?

Comment: You have a 6-core CPU, not a 12-core one. Mathematica should launch 6 kernels on your machine by default, not 12. You probably forced it to launch 12.  *Certain* problems will benefit from more than 6 kernels, but not all of them will.  Some problems will run slower on 12 kernels than on 6.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience usually hyperthreading has no benefit for standard parallel operations at top-level. Here is a little Mathematica script for Linux which shows that there is basically no speed difference between a `Do` loop on a single master kernel or parallel `Do` operations in subkernels. Since `Print` from a subkernel is still pretty much useless in a script environment (even in 11.2, though I am sure it will be fixed in the next version) I changed `ParallelDo` to `ParallelTable`, which has not difference on the speed timings, but allows me to get the subkernel session timings easily.
To be sure to measure correctly I use one less parallel kernel than possible.

```
       rolf@higgs:~$ cat partest.wls
        (
        n = 100000000;
        nminus1cpus = 1;
        Run["cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep 'name'| uniq"];
        Print["number of configured kernels: ", ncpus = $ConfiguredKernels[[1,1]]];
        Print["number of launched Kernels: ", Length @ LaunchKernels[ncpus - nminus1cpus]];
        Print["running ",n, " times on ", ncpus - nminus1cpus ," subkernels"];
        (*round = Function[x, ToString[Round[x 100]/100., OutputForm], Listable];*)
        round = Function[x, ToString[NumberForm[x, {42, 2}], OutputForm], Listable];
        Print[
                  Apply[StringJoin["total parallel time =  ",#1,", sub-kernel-times = ",#2,""]&]@
                  MapAt[StringRiffle[#,"  "]&, 2]@
                  round @
                  AbsoluteTiming @
                  ParallelTable[                  t1 = SessionTime[];
                       Do[i, {i, 1, n, 1}];       t2 = SessionTime[];
                       t2 - t1
                , {j, 1, ncpus - nminus1cpus, 1}]
        ];
        Print["running ", n, " times on the master kernel"];
        Print[ "total time master kernel : ", round @ First @ AbsoluteTiming @ Do[i, {i, 1, n, 1}] ];
        )
```

Running it (the old way, of course wolframscript is also possible):

```
rolf@higgs:~$ math < partest.wls
Mathematica 11.1.1 Kernel for Linux x86 (64-bit)
Copyright 1988-2017 Wolfram Research, Inc.

In[1]:= model name      : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E3-1275 v5 @ 3.60GHz
number of configured kernels: 4
number of launched Kernels: 3
running 100000000 times on 3 subkernels
total parallel time =  5.57, sub-kernel-times = 5.57  5.39  5.35
running 100000000 times on the master kernel
total time master kernel : 5.20
```